# Can non-latin characters appear in slugs?

Tags: urls, slug, multi-language, sanitization

For a non-latin category name such as "我的种类", the slug generated is "%e6%88%91%e7%9a%84%e7%a7%8d%e7%b1%bb". What function does Wordpress use to generate this slug? Can I directly use "我的种类" as the slug? I tried to change the slug from "%e6%88%91%e7%9a%84%e7%a7%8d%e7%b1%bb" to "我的种类" in wordpress database, but when I visited `http://example.com/category/我的种类/`, it showed "Page not found". If I did not do the change, I could visit the category page without a problem by typing `http://example.com/category/%e6%88%91%e7%9a%84%e7%a7%8d%e7%b1%bb/` or `http://example.com/category/我的种类/` in the address bar of my browser. In fact, if I type `http://example.com/category/%e6%88%91%e7%9a%84%e7%a7%8d%e7%b1%bb/`, it is automatically changed to `http://example.com/category/我的种类/` in the address bar,why? And, are non-latin characters not allowed in a url?

Comment: See this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51809/7968

Comment: @QStudio I saw that post but did not get the point. The accepted answer seems to say wordpress 3.3 above supports non-latin characters in slugs. But I use wordpress 5 and it is still encoding the url as %xx.

Comment: But, did you apply the 3 steps listed? make sure you're using WordPress ≥ 3.3
make sure your .htaccess file contains a rule similar to RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
check that your database is UTF-8 encoded (and consider converting to UTF-8 if not).

Comment: @QStudio yes, the .htaccess has that rule and my database uses utf8_general_ci  as the Collation and the tables use utf8mb4_unicode_ci as the Collation.

Comment: I have little experience of working with Chinese characters, seems like there are solutions, but you might need to do some more learning about punycode, UTF and how browsers deal with URI / IRI - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184802/are-chinese-characters-allowed-entered-in-urls#:~:text=Are%20chinese%20characters%20allowed%20to,reach%20to%20the%20related%20page.

Comment: I guess you've tried some plugins also - this one seems recommended - https://wordpress.org/plugins/so-pinyin-slugs/

Comment: Also - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/245121/7968 - good review of this issue by Tom

Comment: @QStudio Thank you!  wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/245121/7968 this post is very helpful.